# When I try to run react for first time on my Windows 10 machine, I get this error in the browser at localhost:3000

Tags: reactjs

Here is the message below about the error.
It turns out that I had to re-install it to fix the error as some package errors occured (thanks to the comment below which hinted that this type of errors comes with package errors.)

```
        TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string. Received type undefined
        at validateString (internal/validators.js:112:11)
        at Object.join (path.js:375:7)
        at noopServiceWorkerMiddleware (C:\myapp1\node_modules\react-dev-utils\noopServiceWorkerMiddleware.js:14:26)
        at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\myapp1\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
        at trim_prefix (C:\myapp1\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:317:13)
        at C:\myapp1\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7
        at Function.process_params (C:\myapp1\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
        at next (C:\myapp1\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
        at launchEditorMiddleware (C:\myapp1\node_modules\react-dev-utils\errorOverlayMiddleware.js:20:7)
        at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\myapp1\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
        at trim_prefix (C:\myapp1\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:317:13)
        at C:\myapp1\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7
        at Function.process_params (C:\myapp1\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
        at next (C:\myapp1\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
        at handleWebpackInternalMiddleware (C:\myapp1\node_modules\react-dev-utils\evalSourceMapMiddleware.js:42:7)
        at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\myapp1\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be better if you showed us your package.json file or your code.
Sometimes this error appears because of deprecated npm packages. We need to see **your code** in order to help you.

Comment: Definitely it's not an answer. It's better to move your answer to 'comments' section.